# Transform file path as a String to "normalized" string in Java

Tags: java, string, filesystems, nio

I'm wondering what is the best way to transform any [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) (platform independent) to a **normalized** path represented as a string.

The requirement is that all the possible Paths that would represent the same object on file system must result in an equal string when *normalized*.

This normalization function must be able to deal with symlinks, non-existent files, relative/absolute paths and other possible gotchas standard filesystems do. It is ok to throw `IOException`.

I think, this could work:

```
public String normalizedFileName(String pathString) throws IOException {
    final Path path = Paths.get(pathString);
    return Files.isReadable(path) ? path.toRealPath().toString() : path.toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
}
```

I will appreciate answers that would explain why my function is not sufficient.

**EDIT:**

This does not work:
Assuming that `/tmp` is a symlink to `/private/tmp`

```
% ls -al / | grep tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel     11 Apr 14  2015 tmp -> private/tmp
```

Following paths don't get correctly normalized (i.e., the assert fails)

```
 assertEquals(
     normalizedFileName("/tmp/non-existent-file.tmp"),
     normalizedFileName("/private/tmp/non-existent-file.tmp")
 );
```

Comment: Why is the normalized form dependent on whether the file is readable by the JVM? At first glance, `path.toRealPath().toString()` seems to do the trick?

Comment: Edited slightly: There's nothing Java 8 specific about this. (`Path` was introduced in Java 7.)

Comment: Note that since you use `Paths.get()` it means the path resolution will always use your default filesystem's resolving mechanism. Make sure this is what you want!

Comment: @aioobe If the file doesn't exist (or better, imho, when it's not readable), you get `NoSuchFileException` when calling `path.toRealPath()`

Comment: @aioobe I know there is nothing specific in my solution. I'm just saying I'm ok with a use of Java 8 libraries in my solution.

Comment: `Files.isSameFile()` works great, except that it fails for non-existent files which is the kind of `IOException` I would like to avoid.